# How to select into table where id equals other id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables `Student` and `PlatoStudents`. `Student.id` equals `PlatoStudents.id`.

How I can migrate from one data to other?

Code where I trying to migrate but it does not work

```
INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, City, Phone, SpecializationId, ProfessionId, IIN, BurnDate, Course)
    SELECT 
        firstname, lastname, patronymic, city, phone, SpecializationId,
        ProfessionID, iinplt, BirthDate, CourseNumber 
    FROM 
        PlatoStudents
    WHERE 
        Students.PlatoId = PlatoStudents.StudentID
```

after your help! My decision (WARNING field must be allow null)

```
UPDATE MY
   SET MY.FirstName = OTHER.firstname,
       MY.LastName = OTHER.patronymic,
       MY.MiddleName = OTHER.lastname,
       MY.City = OTHER.city,
       MY.Phone = OTHER.phone,
       MY.SpecializationId = OTHER.SpecializationId,   
       MY.ProfessionId = OTHER.ProfessionID,   
       MY.IIN = OTHER.iinplt,  
       MY.BurnDate = OTHER.BirthDate,
       MY.Course = OTHER.CourseNumber
FROM Students AS MY
INNER JOIN PlatoStudents AS OTHER
   ON MY.PlatoId = OTHER.StudentID 
WHERE MY.PlatoId = OTHER.StudentID
```

Comment: do you need update or insert

Comment: I can use update to change colums data ?

Comment: First things first, when you have an issue, describe the issue exactly. Saying something "doesn't work" is no help at all.

Comment: ?? BurnDate ??  does not seem to be spelled correctly

Comment: it`s just joke)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to make an update of the values in table Students, with the ones in table PlatoStudents, when matched on id. Try something like this:

```
MERGE INTO Students s -- the target table
USING PlatoStudents ps -- the source table
ON
s.PlatoId = ps.StudentID -- condition for updating
WHEN MATCHED THEN -- when condition is met, do an update 
UPDATE SET
s.Firstname = ps.Firstname,
s.LastName = ps.LastName, 
-- ... continue with all columns here
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN -- when condition not met(e.g.new student), insert it 
INSERT VALUES (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, City, Phone, SpecializationId, ProfessionId, IIN, BurnDate, Course);
```

If you do not need to insert data for non-existing id, leave out the part 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET'.

Answer (score 0):

First, judging by your WHERE clause, it looks like you are trying to use an INSERT statement to insert data into rows where at least some data already exists in the target table.

Since you already have rows in the target table that match the column listed in your WHERE clause, instead using an INSERT for this, you should be using an UPDATE.

An INSERT statement inserts *new rows* into a table. An UPDATE statement allows you to send data into *existing rows* in a target table, replacing any data that may already be in the specified columns in those rows.

Also, just an observation: It looks like you are trying to insert values from a "lastname" column value into a "MiddleName" column in the target table. I realize some cultures have multiple last names, so this may be intentional, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: second database not mine, for me first, second, last for me it is better